# edit pivot tablet with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I need to work with 3 DB tables right now. A domains-table, a tags-table and a pivot-table. In my pivot tables are just 2 foreign_keys of the two "Main-Tables". `domains_id` and `tags_id` are the two foreign keys.

I followed the introduction on this page right here: 
http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

but I still don't understand the "Managing Many-to-Many Relationships: attach-detach-sync" part.

My Controller code for the tags is:

```
 $id = Input::get('id');
    $request = $request->tagging;
    $tags = explode(',', $request);
    $all_tags = [];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag = trim($tag); // entfernen von leerstellen
        $friendly_tags = Str::slug($tag); // user friendly tags
        if (Str::length($friendly_tags)) {
            $all_tags[] = Tags_Domains::create([ 'name' => $friendly_tags ]);
        }
    }

    $domain = Domains::query()->findOrFail($id);
    $domain->tags()->saveMany($all_tags);
```

At the first line in the function I'm getting the ID of the Domain. This ID should be saved in the domains_id attribute in my pivot table.

After this line I format the tags the user want to add and save them into my $all_tags array. For example:

```
$all_tags = [sunny', 'fitness', 'healthy'];
```

Now I'm saving them in my tags table with:

```
Tags_Domains::insert($all_tags);
```

Now I want to save those tag id's in the tags_id attribute in my pivot table. And I still don't know how this is looks like. The laravel doc. wasn't really helpful.

---

my realation in my tags model :

```
public function domains() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\technical\Domains', 'domain_tag', 'id', 'domains_id'); }
```

my realation in my domains model :

```
public function tags() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\technical\Tags_Domains', 'domain_tag', 'id', 'tags_id'); }
```

---

Comment: You don't need the Tags_Domains model, you should only need Tag and Domain models with many-to-many relation defined. Have a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I've added my question. I removed the pivot model and added the line in the bottom of my question to my domains model. -- But I still don't really understand how to use that..

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how you can link a **Tag** to a **Domain**.

If you have a **Tag** object, you can use the **save()** or **$saveMany()** method of the relation to link it:

```
$domain->tags()->save($tag);
$domain->tags()->saveMany([$tag1, $tag2]);
```

If you have an ID, you can use **attach()** to link and **detach()** methods to link/unlink give tag to/from a domain:

```
$domain->tags()->attach($tagId);
$domain->tags()->detach($tagId);
```

Finally, there is the **sync()** method that updates the relation so that it contains only the records whose IDs were passed as an argument. The following will unlink any tags from the domain and then link only tags with ID 1 and 2:

```
$domain->tags()->sync(1,2);
```

In your case, you need to change the way you create **Tags**. Bulk insert like you do will neither give you the tag objects nor tag IDs, so you're gonna need to create them one by one. You can use **saveMany()** to link them to the domain.

Replace

```
$all_tags[] = [ 'tags' => $friendly_tags ];
```

with

```
$all_tags[] = Tag::create([ 'tags' => $friendly_tags ]);
```

And then just do

```
$domain->tags()->saveMany($all_tags);
```

Comment: I gave that a try but i'm getting some errors.. I will try to fix them and write back :)

Comment: Sure, let me know if there are still any issues, there might be typos in the code or in some issues with the rest of your code.

Comment: I updated my question with the current code, I'm still trying some things out :)

Comment: Tags_Domains::insert($all_tags); -- which is confusing me.. this line worked well all the time -- I'll try to fix that

Comment: You don't need this line. You don't need Tags_Domains model. Linking/unlinking should be done using either Tags or Domains model.